# Org Mode Live Preview

Tags: org-mode

I have been creating a lot of markdown documents on VS Code due to the live preview, so headings, formatting and especially LaTeX math code are instantly rendered. This is an indispensable tool when you create documents. I know that you can convert Org documents to various different formats, but live preview is totally different.

So, how can I have this functionality when creating Org files? I have searched but haven't found an adequate solution. It is difficult to believe that something so important doesn't exist, especially since for markdown documents most editors provide it easily and sometimes out of the box.

Comment: Regarding LaTeX, take a look at the documentation like this: M-x eval-expression RET (info "(org) Previewing LaTeX fragments"). There's also a package that can be helpful - https://github.com/io12/org-fragtog.

Comment: @aadcg Thank you for your response. I am already aware of this functionality but it is far too limited and far too cumbersome to be invoked every single time. I am looking for a live preview without the need to be invoked by me every time. Seems very weird that this is not baked into Emacs by default.

Comment: Programmatically executing commands in Emacs every command loop to achieve a live preview is going to be problematic in terms of overhead / speed, but a `condition-case` at the appropriate location might help speed things up if there is an error that prevents the preview buffer from updating (e.g., due to an error or incomplete segment of code being typed in the working buffer).  I would suggest updating the preview buffer on save only, and to generate an error message if update cannot be achieved.